# Can i have a time based trigger to run a function that sets off another time based trigger in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried to do it this way, but when the second trigger is set off it is disabled for an unknown reason.

```
//the first time based trigger that is supposed to run once a day

function startTimeTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('runAuto')
           .timeBased()
           .atHour(14)
           .nearMinute(25)
           .everyDays(1)
           .create();

};

function runAuto() {

  // resets the loop counter if it's not 0
  refreshUserProps();

  // a function that creates the second time based trigger 
  createTrigger();

}

function createTrigger() {

  // Trigger every 1 minute
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('addStats')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use those triggers from an [Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)?

Comment: When you create triggers programatically you should check to make sure that one is not already created.

Comment: @albertovielma Im using the class ScriptApp to make an installable trigger , this is for google sheets. The runAuto trigger works perfectly. What i am trying to do is just to automate the function runAuto for once per day and the only way that i know to do that is to set a trigger that runs that function once per day.

Comment: @MiMi yes i checked the project's triggers if there is something created already, i cleared everything. The problem occurs when the first trigger sets off the function that creates the second trigger, the value for ' Last Run'  for the addStats trigger becomes Disabled.

Comment: Yes. but my point is that you should check it programmatically inside you script every time you run the above script.

Comment: It always amazes how people will say something like `The problem occurs when the first trigger sets off the function that creates the second trigger, the value for ' Last Run' for the addStats trigger becomes Disabled` and then not look at their question to see if there is any foundation what so ever for the other people on the forum to understand what they are talking about` and so we continually have to ask people to provide additional information because we don't know WTH they're talking about because we can't see the problem like they can.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: @MiMi I thought it was clear from the description that i gave and the code that i provided i just didn't mention that it was for 'Last run'. Sorry it is my first ever question on StackOverflow, will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug while running triggers for the new V8 runtime for Google Apps Script. The solution for me was to disable new Apps Script Runtime by Chrome V8 + accessing the triggers by their TriggerId.
This is what it looks like right now:

```
    //I save trigger ID on script properties. You can find it in files > properties > 
   script properties

   function runAuto() {

   clearContents();  

   refreshUserProps();

   var triggerMinID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('addStats');

   if(!triggerMinID){
      createTrigger(); 
    } else {
     deleteTrigger(triggerMinID);
     createTrigger(); 
    }

  }


    function createTrigger() {
     var triggerMin = ScriptApp.newTrigger('addStats')
     .timeBased()
     .everyMinutes(1)
     .create();

      var triggerID = triggerMin.getUniqueId();
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('addStats', triggerID);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only if you delete the old function that uses the same name:

```
  function startTimeTrigger() {

      ScriptApp.newTrigger('runAuto')
          .timeBased()
          .atHour(14)
          .nearMinute(25)
          .everyDays(1)
          .create();

  };

  function runAuto() {

      // resets the loop counter if it's not 0
      refreshUserProps();

      // a function that creates the second time based trigger 
      createTrigger();

  }

  function createTrigger() {
      deleteTrigger('addStats')
      // Trigger every 1 minute
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('addStats')
          .timeBased()
          .everyMinutes(1)
          .create();
  }

  function deleteTrigger(key) {
      var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

      for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
          if (allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === key) {
              ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
          }
      }

  }
```

Comment: The 'addStats' trigger already get's deleted after it is done, this code doesn't change anything. It doesn't even start, just gets disabled when it is set off

Answer (score 0):

A function you might consider using to check if there are any other triggers for the same function.

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```